sound volume bar is moving but sound is not changing ubuntu 24.04
Is anyone facing an issue with ubuntu 24.04, ubuntu 22 as well as popOS, with increasing/decreasing volume for the built in speakers?
When I increase/decrease sound with/for builtin speakers it just kinda makes the quality better but the sound volume stays the same. But when I connect BT headphones it is HQ and volume controls are picking it up. It just doesnt work with the local/builtin speakers...
Adding options snd-hda-intel model=auto to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file didnt work. Nor did installing pulseaudio fix the issue.
Device is Lenovo Yoga Pro 7 (14IRH8), 16GB, i7, rtx4050
Thanks in advance and have a nice day!
